# Why is Google Map generating a static and not a dynamic map

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-maps

I have the following code which displays a Google Map:

```
<div class="col span_1_of_3 gMapHolder">
</div>
```

JQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    alert($(".mapUse").text());
    var k = $(".mapUse").text();
    var embed = "<iframe width='425' height='350' frameborder='0' scrolling='no'  marginheight='0' marginwidth='0'   src='https://maps.google.com/maps?&amp;q=" + encodeURIComponent(k) + "&amp;output=embed&iwloc'></iframe>";
    $(".gMapHolder").html(embed);
});
```

Instead of a dynamic map where I can move around with the mouse, it just displays a static map. I was trying to follow the same method here: [Link to Dyamic Map](http://jsbin.com/emoyup/1/edit?html,js,output)

But I am using a variable instead, for the `encodeURIComponent`.

How do I add the variable and display a dynamic map

Comment: Have you heard of the Google Maps API?

Comment: I can't recreate your problem. Maybe if you post your exact code. Or better yet, make a fiddle

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/36cxLucr/ There you go. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Google seems to have some code that detects the size of the iframe and shows a static image if it's too small. All I did in this test was give it a height of 500px. http://jsfiddle.net/33t9qjvr/

```
.span_1_of_3 {
    width: 100%;
    height: 500px;
}
```